# where is error in my calculation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I try to find zeros of $f'(z)=(z+2)^2+2(z-1)(z+2)(=3z^2+6z=z(3z+6)$ and notice that there is $1+1=2$ zeros, but if I try to solve zeros algebraically, I find;

$$f'(z)=(z+2)^2+2(z-1)(z+2)$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
f'(z)=0 &\iff& (z+2)^2=-2(z-1)(z+2) \\
&\iff& (z+2)=-2(z-1) \\
&\iff& 1=-2
\end{array}
This has no solution.
But still there should be 2 zeros. Where is error?

Comment: There are two errors. How did you go from $(z+2)=-2(z-1)$ to $1=-2$? It doesn't make sense. If $(z+2)=-2(z-1)$ then $z+2=-2z+2$ meaning $3z=0$ and hence $z=0$. This is one valid solution, but you lost a solution by dividing through by $(z+2)$. You may only divide both sides by $(z+2)$ if $(z+2) \neq 0$, i.e. $z \neq -2$. But $z=-2$ is actually a valid solution: What you need to do is expand and solve:

\begin{array}{ccc}
(z+2)^2+2(z-1)(z+2) &=& 0 \\
z^2+4z+4+2(z^2+z-2) &=& 0 \\
3z^2 + 6z &=& 0 \\
3z(z+2) &=& 0
\end{array}

It follows that either $z=0$ or $z=-2$.

Comment: Fly by Night: $(z+2)=-2(z-1) \Leftrightarrow$
$z+2=-2z+2 \Leftrightarrow$
$z=-2z |:z \Leftrightarrow$
$1=-2$

Comment: Shouldn't this be algebra-precalculus rather than complex-analysis?

Comment: @alvoutila It's just like Darly says. If your logic were correct $x=2x \iff 1=2$, $2x=3x \iff 2=3$, and $3x=4x \iff 3=4$. *Either* $x=0$ is a solution to all three of these equations and division by $x$ is forbidden *or* $2=3=4$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You divided by zero.

Never divide unless you are dividing by something you *know* is nonzero. If you really want to divide something that you don't *know* is non-zero, you have to split the problem into two cases:

- One case where the thing you are dividing by is nonzero. (and thus you can divide)
- One case where the thing you are dividing by is zero. (add this as an equation and find another way to continue solving)

The complete set of solutions to the original problem will comprise the solution sets to both of these cases.

Comment: Hurkyl: I get solution $z=0$. Where you get solution $z=-2$?

Comment: In the argument you made, you divided by $z+2$.

Answer (score 2):

$a\cdot b=a\cdot c$ is not equivalent to $b=c$.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma**: Let $z_1,z_2,z_3\in\Bbb C$. Then $z_1z_3=z_2z_3$ if and only if $z_1=z_2$ or $z_3=0$.

**Proof**: Clearly, if $z_1=z_2$, then $z_1z_3=z_2z_3$, and if $z_3=0$, then $z_1z_3=0=z_2z_3$. Thus, the backward direction holds.

It follows from the [zero product property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_product_property) two non-zero complex numbers cannot multiply to get $0$. So, supposing that $z_1\neq z_2$ (that is, that $z_1-z_2\neq 0$) and $z_3\neq 0$, we have that $$(z_1-z_2)z_3\neq 0,$$ so $$z_1z_3-z_2z_3\neq 0,$$ and so $$z_1z_3\neq z_2z_3.$$ The forward direction therefore holds by contrapositive. $\Box$

---

The last line where you're okay is $$(z+2)^2=-2(z-1)(z+2).\tag{$\spadesuit$}$$ By the Lemma, this is equivalent to $$z+2=-2(z-1)\quad\textbf{OR}\quad z+2=0.\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$ Let's look at each of the equations in $(\clubsuit)$ in isolation. I hope it's clear that $z+2=0$ if and only if $z=-2,$ so $(\clubsuit)$ is equivalent to $$z+2=-2(z-1)\quad\textbf{OR}\quad z=-2.\tag{$\diamondsuit$}$$ Now, as you've seen already, we have $z+2=-2(z-1)$ if and only if $z=-2z.$ By the Lemma, $z=-2z$ if and only if $1=-2$ or $z=0.$ Since $1\neq -2$, then $z=-2z$ if and only if $z=0$, so $(\diamondsuit)$ is equivalent to $$z=0\quad\textbf{OR}\quad z=-2.\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$

---

A better approach is to note that $$\begin{align}f'(z) &= (z+2)^2+2(z-1)(z+2)\\ &= \bigl((z+2)+2(z-1)\bigr)(z+2)\\ &= (z+2+2z-2)(z+2)\\ &= 3z(z+2).\end{align}$$ Then use the zero product property to determine the zeros of $f'(z).$

Comment: Cameron Buie: How do you get $z+2=0$?

Comment: Check my edited answer. Hopefully that makes things clearer for you, but if not, let me know what is giving you trouble.